# Is autolayout a must to fit background on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is autolayout a must to fit backgrounds on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4?Specifically talking xib files.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to do auto resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can fit backgrounds without autolayout.  You can use autoresizing (also known as “springs and struts”), or you can do it manually in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.